# Django bulk_create pairs of one-to-one objects

Tags: python, django

I have pair of one-to-one relationships, say:

```
from django.db import models
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Suppose I want to (in my view) create several `Restaurant`s at once, but these restaurant don't have associated `Place`s created yet (and so I would essentially like to create pairs of objects at once).

Is it possible to use `bulk_create` in such a way (i.e. using only O(1) queries)?

Unfortunately I am stuck with MySQL (and not postgre), so I can't simply `bulk_create` the `Place` and access that ID list.

Comment: why don't you create a placeholder entry in Place and use that as the default for all your new Restaurants that do not yet have a real place

Answer (score 0):

If corresponding `Place` objects already exist, you can iterate through places, initialize `Restaurant` objects and then bulk create them.

```
restaurants = [
    Restaurant(place=place) for place in Place.objects.all()
]

Restaurant.objects.bulk_create(restaurants)
```

It will still run the queries for accessing the Place, so if you want O(1) query you'd need to use raw SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately the associated Place's don't exist yet. The point of my question was whether it was possible to create the _pairs_ of objects at once. (Thanks though.)

Comment: What about bulk creating Places and then bulk creating Restaurants? If you need to use one query for inserting in two tables, then you'd need to use raw SQL.

Comment: Two queries is fine, but the issue is that when bulk creating the places, I don't get the pk's of the places, which I need to pass to `bulk_create` for the restaurant.

Comment: It's one extra query, but you could do `place_ids = Place.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: Three queries is also fine :) But this actually grabs _all_ the previous Place's though; I only want the ones I just created.

I guess I could hack it by adding a dummy field to `Place` and then putting some random (unique) number in there, then `filter`ing it out to get those ID's. But I was wondering if there was some nicer way to do this.

Comment: If three queries is fine, then you can retrieve required `Place` object ids using same parameters you used to create them.